# how to show underline on li based on url

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

css

```
a { text-decoration:none }
#nav .category ul li.active { text-decoration:underline; }
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
var url = location.href;
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[1];
      switch(secondLevelLocation) {
      case 'product':
        var val = getQueryString("cate_no");
        $('#nav .category ul li').each(function(index, element) {
            var pageLink = $(this).find('a:eq(0)').attr('href');
            var linkArr = pageLink.split('=');              
            if(linkArr[1] == val) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }           
        });
      }
});
```

html

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="category">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=/product/list.html?cate_no=1>menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href=/product/list.html?cate_no=2>menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href=/product/list.html?cate_no=3>menu3</a></li>
            <li><a href=/product/list.html?cate_no=4>menu4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's really burden to me.

I want to show underline on menu name in each pages.
I searched and found `getQueryString`. But it doesn't works.

Comment: `getQueryString()` isn't a native function.  Could you give us the code for it?

Comment: @landons Thank you for your reply! but I don't know jquery well. What kind of code is it?

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WH3qq/).

In the future, these are helpful for the rest of us :)

Comment: You want to underline the current menu right?

Comment: I missed .split('/'); but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier with a jQuery selector:

```
$('#nav .category a[href="'+window.location.pathname+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: Between `$(function(){` and the final `});`

Comment: Updated to reflect your selectors